# $\ln ab - \ln |b|$

Tags: logarithms

> $\ln ab - \ln |b| = $

Options:

> (a) $\ln a$ ;(b) $\ln|a|$ ;(c) $-\ln a$ ;(d) none of these.

My attempt: $\ln a + \ln b - \ln |b| = \ln a + \ln {\frac{b}{|b|}}$.

Now, $\frac{b}{|b|}=\pm1$, but it can't be $-1$ for log to be defined. So, it means $b$ is positive. So, for $\ln ab$ to be defined, $a$ should be positive too. So, the answer should be option (a). Or, at max both option (a) and (b). But the answer has been given as (b). What's your take?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ could both be negative, and $\ln ab - \ln|b|$ would be defined

Comment: Would $\ln{\frac{b}{|b|}}$ be defined if $b$ is negative?

Comment: no, because $\frac b {|b|}$ would be negative

Comment: Since it is given that $\ln(ab)$ is defined, hence $ab >0$ it follows that $\ln(ab) - \ln |b|=\ln |ab| - \ln |b|= \ln |a|$

Comment: So, then can we not deduce that both $a$ and $b$ should be positive?

Comment: no, only that $ab >0$

Comment: I see, thanks @Conrad.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given answer (b) is correct.

If $\ln ab$ is defined then $ab>0$ so $|ab|=ab.$

Thus $\ln ab-\ln |b|=\ln |ab|-\ln|b|=\ln|a||b|-\ln|b|=\ln|a|+\ln|b|-\ln|b|=\ln|a|.$

Note that it is possible for $a$ and $b$ to be both negative or both positive here.